# Cadena Char* genera mas caracteres que los que deberia

Tags: c++, c, string, gcc, microsoft

Hola tengo un error muy extraño cuando intento llenar una cadena, al final queda con mas caracteres de los que deberia.la consola imprime, la siguiente cadena. Nose si sea por el compilador (Microsoft Cl), porque en compiladores online no sucede o si es un error del carácter \0 al final de la cadena.

```
int main()
{
    int c = 8;
    char * m = new char[c];
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
    {
        *(m+i) =  'A';
        cout << endl << i <<':' << *(m+i) ;
    }
    *m = 'B';
    cout << endl<< m <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
0:A
1:A
2:A
3:A
4:A
5:A
6:A
7:A
BAAAAAAA6f:↨î6
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu conclusión es equivocada.

La cadena no está **generando** más caracteres de los que debe. El problema es que tu cadena no cumple con la regla básica de las [cadenas de texto en `c`/`c++`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadenas_de_texto_en_C), que deben terminar en un caracter `NULL`

> En computación las strings de C son secuencia de caracteres guardados como una matriz de caracteres **terminados con un carácter nulo ('\0' o ASCII 0)**.

En la cita, el énfasis es mío.

Por esta razón, cuando `cout` *lee* la cadena, sigue leyendo hasta que encuentra un caracter nulo (0) en la memoria.

En el ejemplo que pones, imprime:

> ```
> BAAAAAAA6f:↨î6
> ```

Que es tu *cadena* completa, `BAAAAAAA`, más lo que *casualmente* se encontraba en memoria delante de esa variable, antes del primer byte con valor `0`, en este caso fue: `6f:↨î6`. Este valor, por definición, es aleatorio y podría cambiar entre distintas corridas del programa, sobre todo si lo corres en distintos equipos o sistemas operativos.

El valor viene de memoria que podría estar asignada a otras variables en el heap, o reservada para tu programa por el sistema operativo, aunque no la esté usando actualmente.

Si por alguna razón no se encontrase ningún 0 en el camino, tu programa podría intentar leer memoria en una dirección que no tiene reservada, lo que, en sistemas operativos modernos, provocaría un error de protección general (GPF: General Protection Fault).

Lo que debes hacer es, siempre, reservar espacio extra para el caracter `NULL` y, en caso de duda, asegurarte de que el último caracter de tu cadena tenga este valor.

En este caso, podría ser algo como:

```
int main()
{
    int c = 8;
    char * m = new char[c+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
    {
        *(m+i) =  'A';
        cout << endl << i <<':' << *(m+i) ;
    }
    *m = 'B';
    *m+c = 0;
    cout << endl<< m <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Las cadenas en C deben incluir entre sus elementos un byte de valor 0 que indica dónde termina. Es lo que espera el operador `cout <<` para saber dónde debe parar de emitir caracteres por pantalla.

En tu caso, al crear array de 8 char, el compilador los ha llenado todos con bytes de valor 0. Por tanto, mientras vas metiendo letras, siempre hay un 0 después de la última que hayas metido. Por ejemplo, tras meter 3 veces la 'A' tendrás:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|'A'|'A'|'A'| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Por tanto si en este momento hicieras `cout << m` se emitirían por pantalla tres 'A' y al encontrar el byte de valor 0 ya no se emitiría más.

Pero cuando has llenado los 7 elementos con 'A' y sustituyes el primero por una 'B' la situación de tu array es:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|'B'|'A'|'A'|'A'|'A'|'A'|'A'|'A'|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

en el que como podemos ver no hay ningún 0. Por tanto `cout << m` comenzará a escribir letras, las primeras las mostrará correctamente ("BAAAAAAA") pero después seguirá mostrando los contenidos que haya en la memoria más allá de la última "A", aún si no pertenecen a este array.

En algún momento, casualmente, encontrará un byte de valor 0 y se detendrá, pero hasta entonces estará volcando los contenidos "basura" que haya en la memoria. No son basura en realidad, sino otras variables de tu programa, que no contienen códigos ASCII válidos y por eso se ven así.

Podría suceder incluso que a la hora de volcar contenidos de memoria no se encuentre un 0 que le haga detenerse, e intente acceder a direcciones que ya no son de tu programa. En ese caso se produciría una excepción en la propia CPU (por acceder a memoria protegida), que causaría que el operativo entre y aborte tu programa. El típico *segmentation fault*.

**Moraleja**. En un array de tamaño 8, no puedes meter una letra, pues siempre hay que reservar un espacio adicional para el caracter nulo (el cero que termina la cadena). En tu array por tanto sólo caben 7 letras.